# MAUI Problem with showing/refreshing items on ListView

Tags: c#, .net, maui

I have a problem. When I clicked "numberOfVariables" button I don't see any fields in listView. Neither previously entered nor newly added to ObservableCollection. I need this to set list if variables.

What I do wrong? In UWP is working exacly.

MainPage.xaml

```xml
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="Calc.Pages.MainPage"
         xmlns:local="using:Calc.ViewModels">
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <local:CalculatorViewModel/>
</ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <StackLayout>
        <Entry x:Name="numberOfVariables" Placeholder="0"/>
        <Button Text="Dalej" Clicked="SetNumbersOfVariables"/>
        <StackLayout x:Name="calcLayout" IsVisible="false">
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Variables}" >
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <StackLayout Background="red">
                                <Label Text="nowy"/>
                                <Entry x:Name="{Binding Name}"
                                       Placeholder="name"/>
                                <Entry x:Name="{Binding Value}"
                                        Placeholder="0" />
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

MainPage.cs

```cs
namespace Calc.Pages;
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    internal CalculatorViewModel viewModel { get; set; }
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        viewModel = new CalculatorViewModel();
    }

    private void SetNumbersOfVariables(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (numberOfVariables.Text == null)
            return;

        _ = int.TryParse(numberOfVariables.Text.ToString(), out int nrOf);
        viewModel.SetNumberOfVariables(nrOf);
        calcLayout.IsVisible = true;
    }
}
```

Variable.cs

```cs
namespace Calc.Models
{
    public class Variable
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public float Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

CalculatorViewModel.cs

```cs
namespace Calc.ViewModels
{
    public class CalculatorViewModel 
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Variable> Variables = new()
        {
            new Variable()
            {
                Name = "x",
                Value = 1
            },
               new Variable()
            {
                Name = "y",
                Value = 2
            }
        };

        internal void SetNumberOfVariables(int nrOf)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < nrOf; i++)
                Variables.Add(new Variable());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that your code actually looks like this? For example, you write "CalculatorViewModel.cs", but then you show the declaration of a `MainPage` that inherits from `ContentPage` but with the `ObservableCollection` which belongs into the ViewModel. Also, in the XAML you're binding to `Variables2` which doesn't exist in the code you provided. You may want to update the code in the question to reflect the actual situation.

Comment: Sory, someting went wrong. I have not notice. I update code. This is what I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Original answer

You're not setting the `BindingContext` correctly. You don't need to set it in the XAML, so remove it from there and fix the code-behind like below:

**XAML**

```xml
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"          
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Calc.Pages.MainPage"         
             xmlns:local="using:Calc.ViewModels">
  <StackLayout>
    <Entry x:Name="numberOfVariables" Placeholder="0"/>
    <Button Text="Dalej" Clicked="SetNumbersOfVariables"/>
    <StackLayout>
        <Entry x:Name="numberOfVariables" Placeholder="0"/>
        <Button Text="Dalej" Clicked="SetNumbersOfVariables"/>
        <StackLayout x:Name="calcLayout" IsVisible="false">
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Variables}" >
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <StackLayout Background="red">
                                <Label Text="nowy"/>
                                <Entry x:Name="{Binding Name}"
                                       Placeholder="name"/>
                                <Entry x:Name="{Binding Value}"
                                        Placeholder="0" />
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

**Code-behind**

Here you should set the `BindingContext` instead:

```cs
namespace Calc.Pages;
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    private CalculatorViewModel viewModel;
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = viewModel = new CalculatorViewModel();
    }

  //...
}
```

**Remarks**

Note that your `Variables` class doesn't implement the [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged) interface, which means that your View won't receive updates for the values that you're binding to. There are libraries like the [CommunityToolkit.Mvvm](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm) for that.

Also, you may want to reconsider how you're parsing the input text:

```cs
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(numberOfVariables.Text))
{
    return;
}

if (int.TryParse(numberOfVariables.Text, out int nrOf))
{
    viewModel.SetNumberOfVariables(nrOf);
}
```

## Update

I noticed that your `Variables` collection is a field, not a property. You need to change it to a property by providing at least a getter for the binding to work:

```cs
namespace Calc.ViewModels
{
    public class CalculatorViewModel 
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Variable> Variables { get; set; } = new()
        {
            new Variable()
            {
                Name = "x",
                Value = 1
            },
               new Variable()
            {
                Name = "y",
                Value = 2
            }
        };

        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I changing my cod but is still not working. As far as value changes, I don't need it. I added some at the beginning to see if it would work.

I rapair that and this is working code: (need to set private ObservableCollection in viewmodel constructor first and bind it to public variable, but BindingContext also must be on constructor as you wrote)

MainPage.xaml

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="Calc.Pages.MainPage"
         xmlns:local="using:Calc.ViewModels">
<StackLayout>
    <Entry x:Name="numberOfVariables"
   Placeholder="0"/>
    <Button Text="Dalej" Clicked="SetNumbersOfVariables"/>
    <StackLayout x:Name="calcLayout" IsVisible="false">
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Variables}" >
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout>
                            <Entry x:Name="{Binding Name}"
                                   Placeholder="name"/>
                            <Entry x:Name="{Binding Value}"
                                    Placeholder="0" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
  internal CalculatorViewModel viewModel { get; set; }

  public MainPage()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    BindingContext = viewModel = new CalculatorViewModel();
  }

  private void SetNumbersOfVariables(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(numberOfVariables.Text))
        return;

    if(int.TryParse(numberOfVariables.Text.ToString(), out int nrOf))
        viewModel.SetNumberOfVariables(nrOf);

    calcLayout.IsVisible = true;
  }
}
```

CalculatorViewModel.cs

```
public class CalculatorViewModel 
{
    private ObservableCollection<Variable> _variables;

    public ObservableCollection<Variable> Variables { get { return _variables; } }

    public CalculatorViewModel() 
    { 
        _variables = new ObservableCollection<Variable>();
    }
    internal void SetNumberOfVariables(int nrOf)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < nrOf; i++)
            _variables.Add(new Variable());
    }
}
```

I don't know why I didn't do it right away. I guess it shouldn't change anything.

P.S. In UWP is not need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged when you manipulate on the ObservableCollection. I test it and when you add new one to list in MAUI is working same.

Comment: Essentially, you followed my advice, but I found out why the collection still wasn't updating. It needs to be a property, but you had it defined as a field before. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: I changing previously... thanks